# Java Robot on linux - no uppercase characters ( using x11vnc )

Tags: java, linux, shift, awtrobot

I am trying to simulate keyboard on my vps server with debian lenny using **Java Robot Class**. I am watching results using these commands (to connect with VNCviewer):

```
Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1366x768x16 & fluxbox & x11vnc -display :2 -bg -usepw -nomodtweak -xkb
```

I can type lower case letters but it doesn't work with capital letters. I used following code from the internet + my modifications:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class TypingRobot extends Robot {

public TypingRobot() throws AWTException {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public void keyType(int keyCode) {
 keyPress(keyCode);
 delay(50);
 keyRelease(keyCode);
}

public void keyType(int keyCode, int keyCodeModifier) {

 keyPress(keyCodeModifier);
 keyPress(keyCode);  
 delay(50);
 keyRelease(keyCode);
 keyRelease(keyCodeModifier);
}


public void type(String text) {
  //String textUpper = text.toUpperCase();
  String textUpper = text;

  for (int i=0; i<text.length(); ++i) {
   typeChar(textUpper.charAt(i));
  }  
 }

 private void typeChar(char c) {
  boolean shift = true;
  int keyCode;


  switch (c) {
  case '~':
   keyCode = (int)'`';
   break;
  case '!':
   keyCode = (int)'1';
   break;
  case '@':
   keyCode = (int)'2';
   break;
  case '#':
   keyCode = (int)'3';
   break;
  case '$':
   keyCode = (int)'4';
   break;
  case '%':
   keyCode = (int)'5';
   break;
  case '^':
   keyCode = (int)'6';
   break;
  case '&':
   keyCode = (int)'7';
   break;
  case '*':
   keyCode = (int)'8';
   break;
  case '(':
   keyCode = (int)'9';
   break;
  case ')':
   keyCode = (int)'0';
   break;
  case ':':
   keyCode = (int)';';
   break;
  case '_':
   keyCode = (int)'-';
   break;
  case '+':
   keyCode = (int)'=';
   break;
  case '|':
   keyCode = (int)'\\';
   break;
  case '?':
   keyCode = (int)'/';
   break;
  case '{':
   keyCode = (int)'[';
   break;
  case '}':
   keyCode = (int)']';
   break;
  case '<':
   keyCode = (int)',';
   break;
  case '>':
   keyCode = (int)'.';
   break;
  case '/':
   keyCode = 47;
   shift = false;
   break;
  case ' ':
   keyCode = (int)' ';
   shift = false;
   break;
  case '.':
   keyCode = (int)'.';
   shift = false;
   break; 
  default:
   if( (int)c>=65 && (int)c<=90 ){
       keyCode = (int)c;
   }
   else{
   keyCode = (int)c-32;
   shift = false;
   }
  }
  if (shift)
   keyType(keyCode, KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  else
   keyType(keyCode);
 } }
```

My input looks like:

```
robot.type("Some string...");
```

but it changes capital letters to small ones. I think there is some problem with my server because Windows version of this code worked well for me. I can press SHIFT on VNCviewer and it works but probably Robot/x11vnc or something related can't press it for me.

Any ideas how to enable SHIFT key? (I tested CAPSLOCK too, nothing happened too)

Comment: In a comments of (http://gruimed.blogspot.ru/2009/09/using-java-robot-to-type-text-strings.html) - where I suppose you've obtained your code - there is a last comment that uses Clipboard instead of keypresses - you could give it a try/

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov - thank you for your response. Unfortunately this didn't work too, but it helped me to find the solution for my problem. The main problem was not java code but thix x11vnc app which doesn't like shift/ctrl/altt and other characters. I used tightvncserver instead and everything is working well now.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is - do not use x11vnc, shift/ctrl/alt keys not working there. Use **tightvncserver** instead.